# What do you call someone who is favored by a higher authority?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who is favored by a higher authority, such as in the work place they get more perks than other people...teacher's pet?

Comment: We often literally use "*favorite*".  Seriously.

Comment: Mmm replace work-place with life and you get "blessed".

Comment: @DanBron, yes, seriously or otherwise. Shades of [Piers Gaveston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Gaveston,_1st_Earl_of_Cornwall)!

Comment: "Blessed" is what I would think of first.  You can also say "knighted", "star", "baby" (with the right context), "fair-haired boy", "anointed", etc.  These are almost always used with a bit of sarcasm (and, of course, would rarely be appropriate for official communications).

Answer (score 7):

**Protege** or **protégé**

> a person who is protected and aided by the patronage of another person

([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/protege))

> one who is protected or trained or whose career is furthered by a person of experience, prominence, or influence

([Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9))

Origin:

> 1778, from French protégé (fem. protégée) "one who is protected," noun use of past participle of Middle French protéger "protect," from Latin protegere

A person may be an acknowledged protege, where it is widely understood that he/she receives special treatment as part of preparation for a future job assignment. Or that person may be disparagingly referred to as a protege by others who feel the treatment is undeserved.

Comment: I remember talking to a guy many years ago about the fact that he was one of half-a-dozen "acknowledged proteges" within a big multinational, all being "groomed" for a single senior position that only one of them would be likely to occupy (in 2-3 decades time, if ever). In his opinion, others within the organisation would inevitably refer to his status "disparagingly" anyway. But he considered it part of his job to both learn how to deal with that in his own mind *and* to reduce it (by becoming respected and/or liked), so that he'd be successful if he ever got that top slot.

Comment: I have never, ever - for say 200 years - heard protege used that way.  (I mean in English.)  It's kind of "just silly" to give an ancient usage of a word. A protege is now just a student, the "best student" ... the "padawan" if you will .. not the teacher's pet

Comment: I fear that sometimes voting on this site, is, people who are not native speakers or are just learning English, who see the quoted dictionary definition and then upvote

Comment: Someone who's "favored" doesn't necessarily mean they're a protege.

Comment: Apparently there is a trend among some that words should only have the meanings that they are familiar with and that any suggestion that language has more depth and dimension than they have experienced is irrelevant. It's okay to use words in the way they are defined in the dictionary. We have dictionaries and other references to hold the vast amount of information that won't readily fit inside small minds.

Answer (score 6):

"**A blue-eyed boy**" (in BrE and AusE, according to [FDE](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+blue-eyed+boy))

> - "a blue-eyed boy" (noun, informal) a person highly regarded by someone and treated with special favor. ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blue-eyed-boy)) The favourite, especially a young one, of especially someone in power. [WK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blue-eyed_boy)

e.g.

- He was very much **the blue-eyed boy** in the office.
- It's no use complaining to the manager about Jerry. He is **his blue-eyed boy**.

"teacher's pet" as you suggested, also fits.  As well as "fair-haired boy"

Comment: clever answer..

Comment: I'm a native English speaker and I've never heard this phrase.

Comment: Also, [**golden child**](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/147624-golden-child).

Comment: "Fair-haired child" is far more common in the US.  I've maybe heard "blue-eyed boy" twice in 60 years.

Answer (score 3):

Teacher’s pet, yes, perhaps, if you are looking for a term of abuse (which may indeed be applied metaphorically outside the schoolroom setting). But I would suggest ***[connected](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/connected)***:

> having useful social, professional, or commercial relationships [M-W]

You can even use this when the “higher authority” in question is supernatural, or mafioso, or what you will.

Comment: much better answers

Answer (score 2):

[anointed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anoint)

> anoint - to choose by or as if by divine election; also :  to designate as if
>   by a ritual anointment

Example of use:

> From the beginning of his rise with George Bush until the day of his
>   abrupt resignation, Alberto Gonzales was anointed, directed and
>   protected by Karl Rove.

from ["The puppet that lost its master"](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2007/aug/28/puppetlostitsmaster)

Used to describe someone, you could say they are "the anointed one".

Comment: *The anointed one* is a literal translation of the Greek ὁ Χριστός, the Christ.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider also the expression, ***[have friends in  high places](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+friends+in+high+places):***

> - to know important people who can help you get what you want.
>
>   - He has plenty of friends in high places willing to support his political career.

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

chosen one

> chosen one - sole person chosen by destiny to stop an impending disaster that threatens all life

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=the%20chosen%20one)

Comment: What is the source of the quotation, if indeed it is one? (That shaded formatting, invoked by a greater-than sign at the left edge of the text field, is nominally for quotations.)